# How to make diagonal entries of a matrix 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, statistics, positive-definite

I am trying to generate a positive definite matrix $\mathbf{M} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ with diagonal entries equal to 1. For this, I am first sampling $\mathbf{W} \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times n}$, then putting $\mathbf{M}' = \mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}^T$. Let $\mathbf{D}$ be the diagonal entries of $\mathbf{M}'$, then $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{D}^{-0.5}\mathbf{W}\mathbf{W}^T(\mathbf{D}^{-0.5})^T$. This will give a positive definite matrix with diagonal entries 1. But is there a way to generate desired matrix by using $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{W}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{W}^T$ formula for some $\mathbf{D}$?

Edit 1: For a fixed $\mathbf{W}$ matrix, $\mathbf{D}$ needs to be sampled in such a way that $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{W}\mathbf{D}\mathbf{W}^T$

Comment: You may want to note that $D_{i,i}= \|W_i\|_2^2$ where $W_i$ is the $i$-th row of $W$. So if you fix $D$ you may just want to sample $W$ fixing the $\|-\|_2$ norms of its rows.

Comment: Do you mean: first generate $W \in \mathbb{R}^{k\times n}$, then ask if there exists a diagonal $D$ (function of $W$) such that $WDW^\mathsf{T}$ has diagonal entries $1$?

Comment: @RiverLi Yes, you are right.

Comment: Then this is a linear programming problem. $M=WDW^T$ is just a (usually overdetermined) system of $k^2$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns. Adding also the $n$ inequality constraints $d_i>0$ for $i=1,2,\ldots,n$, you get a linear program.

Comment: @user1551 I think it is a system of $k$ linear equation and $n$ unknowns, if $n < k $, then we won't have a solution, right?